# Cardinality of atomless sigma-algebras

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, boolean-algebra

I know that an infinite $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ has at least cardinality $\mathfrak{c}=2^{\aleph_0}$.

Suppose now that $\mathcal{A}$ is $\alpha$-generated ($\alpha>\omega$). Clearly, $\mathcal{A}$ is atomless. But what is its cardinality precisely?

Edit: By $\alpha$-generated I mean that the set of generators of $\mathcal{A}$ has size $\alpha$.

Comment: What is the meaning of being $\alpha$-generated? Does it mean the $\sigma$-algebra is generated by a collection of size $\alpha$?

Comment: "The" set of generators? "A" set of generators? And I don't get why $\mathcal{A}$ should be atomless: if you add a point $lala$ to the space, and consider que $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A} \cup \{\{lala\}\}$, it has an atom, right? Is this new $\sigma$-algebra not $\alpha$-generated anymore?

Comment: To add to what @Plop said, if you take any uncountable set, $X$, then the set of countable and co-countable subsets of $X$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that is generated by the singletons, of which there are $|X|$.

Comment: (Also, when you write $\omega$, I read it as an ordinal so $\alpha>\omega$ could very well be any other countable ordinal. What you really mean is that $\alpha$ is uncountable, so either write $\alpha>\aleph_0$ to indicate that we are thinking about $\alpha$ as a cardinal, or $\alpha\geq\omega_1$ to indicate that it is actually uncountable.)

Comment: @Plop The sigma-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}\cup\{\{lala\}\}$ is not the sigma-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$ anymore. My understanding is that since intersections in $\mathcal{A}$ are at most countable, if I have an uncountable set of generators, then there are no atoms in $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you are thinking about a $\sigma$-algebra that is **freely** generated by a set of size $\alpha$?

Comment: @Ben: I don't understand what you are saying, so we might disagree on the definition of "generated". Could you write it down what it means for you? For me, a set $A$ of subsets of $X$ generates a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ if $\mathcal{A}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $A$.

Answer (score 1):

An $\alpha$-generated sigma-algebra $\mathcal A$ has
$$
\alpha \le |\mathcal A| \le \alpha^{\aleph_0}
$$
In case $\alpha=\alpha^{\aleph_0}$, this answers the question.

The fact you refer to in the question is: there is no sigma-algebra with
$$
\aleph_0 \le |\mathcal A| < \mathfrak c = \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}
$$
so we conclude that an infinite countably-generated sigma algebra has power exactly $\mathfrak c$.

---

Let $\mathcal A$ be a sigma-algebra on a set $X$ generated by $\mathcal G$ with $|\mathcal G| = \alpha$.  Here is a proof for $|\mathcal A| \le \alpha^{\aleph_0}$

Let $\Omega$ be the set of all countable ordinals.  We recursively define
sets $\mathcal G_\lambda \subseteq \mathcal P(X)$
for $\lambda \in \Omega$ as follows.

$\bullet\;\mathcal G_0 = \mathcal G$

$\bullet\;\mathcal G_{\lambda+1}$ is the set of all countable unions $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ where, for each $n$, either $E_n \in \mathcal G_\lambda$ or $X\setminus E_n \in \mathcal G_\lambda$.

$\bullet\;$If $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal, then
$$
\mathcal G_\lambda = \bigcup_{\gamma < \lambda}\mathcal G_\gamma .
$$

Then:
$$
\sigma(\mathcal G) = \bigcup_{\lambda \in \Omega}\mathcal G_\lambda
$$
and we may prove recursively that
$|\mathcal G_\lambda| \le \alpha^{\aleph_0}$ for all $\lambda \in \Omega$.

Next, $|\Omega| = \aleph_1 \le \mathfrak c = 2^{\aleph_0} \le \alpha^{\aleph_0}$, so
$$
|\sigma(\mathcal G)| = \left|\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Omega}\mathcal G_\lambda\right| \le \aleph_1\cdot\alpha^{\aleph_0}
\le \alpha^{\aleph_0}\cdot \alpha^{\aleph_0} = \alpha^{\aleph_0} .
$$